# Approving tokens after flash loan

Tags: 0x, flash-loans, aave

I'm creating a smart contract that can both make flash loans and swap tokens via 0x. I can call the flash loan and token swap functions just fine, but when I try to call the token swap within the flash loan callback, I get the error: `execution reverted: SafeERC20: low-level call failed`.

If I understand this error correctly, I believe this means I'm not approving the tokens properly. Here's the gist of what my code looks like:

```
/// Make a flash loan.
function makeFlashLoan(...) {
    IERC20(borrowedTokenAddress).approve(zrxSpender, uint256(-1));
    lendingPool.flashLoan(...);
}

/// Callback for flash loan.
function executeOperation(...) {
    IERC20(borrowedTokenAddress).approve(lendingPoolAddress, uint256(-1));
    swapOnZrx(...);
}

/// Swap a token on 0x.
function swapOnZrx(...) {
    IERC20(fromToken).approve(zrxSpender, uint256(-1));
    ...
    (bool success,) = _swapTarget.call(_swapCallData);
    ...
}
```

If I make a transaction to just call `swapOnZrx`, the transaction succeeds. Similarly, if I make a transaction to just call `makeFlashLoan` with `swapOnZrx` commented out, the transaction also succeeds. However, When I call `makeFlashLoan` with the call to `swapOnZrx`, I keep getting the SafeERC20 error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with this error for almost an entire day :(

Answer (score 2):

Yikes. Turns out this was happening since I wasn't paying back my flashloan.